# Cannot get link id inside previous span using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get the `id` value of previous `a` which is inside a `span`. The result should be: `1234`

**HTML:**

```
<li> 
    <span> <a href="#" class="inline">Some other post</a>  </span><br>          
    <span class="foo">Post <a href="/fantastic-post" class="inline" id="1234">Fantastic post</a></span>       
    <button onclick="getPostId(this);">Click</button>
</li>
```

What I've tried (among others):

```
function getPostId (elem) {
    var id = $(elem).prev('span a').attr('id');
    alert ('post id is:' ,  id );
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a previous `span` first, and then find `a` which is a child of that `span`. Additionally, you need to concatenate the string in the `alert` box:

```js
function getPostId(elem) {
  var id = $(elem).prev('span').find('a').attr('id');
  alert('post id is:' + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <span> <a href="#" class="inline">Some othe posrt</a>  </span><br>
  <span class="foo">Post <a href="/fantastic-post" class="inline" id="1234">Fantastic post</a></span>
  <button onclick="getPostId(this);">Click</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with onclick and just give the button a **class**:

```
<button class='click_button'>Click</button>
```

...then **listen** for the button's class:

```
$('.click_button').click(function() {
alert($(this).prev().find('a').attr('id'))
})
```